# How to hide remove button if there is no record remaining?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am facing issue while append data to front-end. I am displaying the data into chunk of 10.
Issue is if record is 10,  load more button should be hidden, but button is still visible. How to fix this issue?

Image:

[image]

> Ajax:

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    window.onload = function() {
         
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get_jobs",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                "_token": $('#csrf-token').content,
                "counter": counter,
            },
            success: function(response){
                if (response.count < 10){
                        $('#seeMore').hide();
                }
                else{
                     $('#seeMore').show();
                    var data = response.all_jobs;
                    append_data(data);
                counter++;
                }
                
            }
        });
    };

   async function append_data(data){
       for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           console.log("1 for");
           var html = ' <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 content aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1100" data-aos-once="true" style="margin-bottom: 16px;"><a href="jobdetail/'+data[i].id+'" class="d-flex justify-content-between bg-white rounded-10 px-8 pl-lg-13 pr-lg-11 py-9 py-lg-10 align-items-center mb-5 job-card-hover gr-hover-shadow-5 job" style="min-height:250px"><div class="texts"><h3 class="gr-text-6 font-weight-bold text-blackish-blue mb-4">'+data[i].job_title+'</h3><p class="gr-text-9 mb-0 gr-color-blackish-blue-opacity-7">'+data[i].company+'</p></div><div class="card-icon"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right gr-text-8 text-storm"></i></div></a></div>';
           $(html).hide().appendTo("#job_section").fadeIn(1000);
       }
    }

        $("#seeMore").click(function(e){

            $.ajax({
                url: "/get_jobs",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    "_token": $('#csrf-token').content,
                    "counter": counter,
                },
                success: function(response){
                    if (response.count < 10){
                        console.log("2 if");
                        $('#seeMore').hide();
                    }
                    console.log("2 else")
                    var data = response.all_jobs;
                    append_data(data);
                    counter++;
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

> Controller:

```
public function getjobs(Request $request){

    $all_jobs = DB::table('jobs')->skip($request->counter*10)->take(10)->where('job_status', 1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();

   return response(["all_jobs" => $all_jobs, "count" => count($all_jobs)]);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json when there's no more results then `next_page_url` would be null

Comment: @apokryfos This method reload the page, i need to load data without page load.

Comment: I linked the json results which you can read in your ajax response

Comment: does my answer help you?

Comment: No Brother @Abilogos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

all **benefits** of pagination is **to not** load all data with one request. and prevent sending a lot of data is optimizing in **page load, bandwidth saving, server resources, client resources ....

as @apokryfos suggested laravel has a bulit-in function (**paginate**) to take care of this.

but as i see, you are sending **all of your records** within just **one request** , and believe its not a good practice at all.

### Fix

you wrote:

```
if (response.count < 10)
```

which takes care of 0-9 items, if you want to hide on 10 items you could:

```
if (response.count =< 10)
```

bit it would be a real **paginate** if you send data chunks. with attributes like **total,page_number,...**

it can be simply with using of laravel paginate:

```
return DB::table('jobs')->where('job_status',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate();
```

it gets the **page_number** from request

as Laravel Document suggested you can just grab the next page url from **next_page_url** and change the next button :

```
$("#seeMore").attr("href",next_page_url);
```